# How do I mock return value for handleSubmit from react-hook-form during tests?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs, react-hook-form

I'm currently trying to test my form which has some very nested components and complex logic. So rather than actually mocking the userEvents and then submitting the form I want to mock a return value for `handleSubmit`

This is my react component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormProvider, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export const MyForm = (): JSX.Element => {
    const methods = useForm<{ name: string }>();

    const onSubmit = async (data: { name: string }): Promise<void> => {
        console.log(data);

        // logic to handle data.name
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <FormProvider {...methods}>
                <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <div>{/* deeply nested components */}</div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                        <button>Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </FormProvider>
        </div>
    );
};
```

And this is my test:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

jest.mock('react-hook-form', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-hook-form'),
    // handleSubmit: console.log('This log works when submitted'),
    handleSubmit: () => jest.fn().mockReturnValue({name: 'test'})
}));

describe('MyForm', () => {
    test('handles onSubmit correctly', async () => {
        render(<MyForm />);

        userEvent.click(screen.getByText('Submit'));
    });
});
```

So this is how much I've been able to mock. When I use userEvent to click the submit button. I can do a console.log in the test per above. But when I try to mock a value, in my React component inside the `onSubmit` function, the `console.log(data)` returns an empty object.

How can I mock it so that `console.log(data)` returns `{name: 'test'}` in my onSubmit function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend **not** mocking `useForm` at all. This goes against the [guiding principles](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles) of `@testing-library`.

Instead, use async testing utilities like `waitFor` and `findBy*`. See the `react-hook-form` docs at https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#TestingForm for examples like this one:

```
it("should display required error when value is invalid", async () => {
  fireEvent.submit(screen.getByRole("button"));

  expect(await screen.findAllByRole("alert")).toHaveLength(2);
  expect(mockLogin).not.toBeCalled();
});
```